# Создать синоним метки vkapi/vkontakte-api

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю сделать метку [vkapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkapi) синонимом для [vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api).

Comment: Синоним создан.